# Raspbian: evaluate conditional strings and/or numbers

Tags: debian, shell-script, string, expr

I am having a really a hard time to evaluate conditional strings and numbers.
After hours of reading and trying with ([my Beginners Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)) I keep getting the error msgs like `syntax error in conditional expression`,  `unary operator expected`, `conditional binary operator expected` etc..

Something is wrong inside the if-condition - but I don't get it.
I tried with arithmetic operators `-ge`, `-le` but that didn't work either. 
Please, no worries about the debatable logic of this code-snip.

Working with Raspbian (Debian) on my Raspberry.

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=syslogd
PID=/var/run/$NAME.pid
PIDofP=`pidof $NAME`

    if [[ $PIDofP = "" ]]   #empty, at least not visible 
    then
        echo "   No process is running."
    fi

    if [[ $PIDofP < 1000 ]]
    then
        echo "   The PID-number is lower than 1000. ($PID: $PIDofP)"
    fi

    if [[ "$PIDofP" > 999 ]]
    then
        echo "   The PID-number is higher than 1000. ($PID: $PIDofP)"
    fi  
exit 0
```

Is there a way to evaluate a string, number, integer or whatever to learn what kind it is? Say I just have a bunch of numbers and/or letters and want to know about the 'format' they are held in - to be used afterwards, hopefully without spending hours finding the proper syntax.

Sorry, first time writing bash.script

Comment: What do you want the script to do? Is your problem that you get both the "No process named: $NAME is running" message *and* the "The PID-number is lower than 1000." when the PID is blank?

Comment: Basically I want to compare real number values instead of 'lexical' values and yes, the return of `pidof`may be blank. Correct: $NAME will throw an error (edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unary operator expected` error was likely due to `$PIDofP` not being in quotes in the conditional. In that case when `$PIDofP` is an empty string the shell sees no value at all on the left side of `=` instead of a blank value, hence the error message.

The following snippet implements the PID comparison logic correctly through the use of `if`/`elif`/`else`, which guarantees only one of the three possible `echo` outputs is generated. It uses the POSIX comparison syntax (see [What is the difference between double and single square brackets in bash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash)).

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=syslogd
PID=/var/run/$NAME.pid
PIDofP=`pidof $NAME`
if [ "$PIDofP" = "" ]; then
    echo "   No process is running."
elif [ "$PIDofP" -lt 1000 ]; then
    echo "   The PID number is lower than 1000. ($PID: $PIDofP)"
else
    # $PIDofP is >= 1000.
    echo "   The PID number is 1000 or higher. ($PID: $PIDofP)"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Also for that link. Will have to study all that. Happy Holidays.